# How can I use matlab code in C# to work in windows phone?

Tags: matlab, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, signal-processing

I'm hopping to run some signal processing algorithm in windows phone app. So I need to combine matlab m files with C# gui.

Comment: I honestly think it would be much easier to setup a remote MATLAB server and just send requests from your phone to the server. MATLAB and MCR take up a lot of space and have some pretty beefy requirements, and your phone will likely not be able to run it even if you do figure out how to get it loaded. Why not just write your own implementation or look for an open source library written in C,C++, or C#? It would probably run more efficiently as well.

Comment: .NET Framework has some of this built in, and is compatible with Windows 8 Phone http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/10/30/announcing-the-release-of-the-net-framework-for-windows-phone-8.aspx

Comment: Most of the MATLAB algorithms comes with full source code available (C or C++ code I believe). Your best best is to port these to C# (I did something similar back in the day after prototyping in matlab and later making it real as an app)

Comment: @dotMorten Only a subset of MATLAB algorithms are implemented in C or C++, and none of them have the source available.

Comment: For some reason this question is on hold as unclear - I'm not sure why, it seems perfectly clear to me. You have two options to integrate MATLAB code into a Windows phone app. i) As @MZimmerman6 suggests, deploy your code to a web service with MATLAB Builder NE, and have your C# app call that. ii) Use MATLAB Coder to convert your algorithm to C, and integrate that C code directly into your C# app. You would need to make sure that your algorithm falls into the subset of the MATLAB language supported by MATLAB Coder, but if it is primarily a signal processing algorithm it is likely that it will.

Comment: @SamRoberts reopened - can you move your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to integrate MATLAB code into a Windows phone app.

1. Deploy your code to a web service on a remote server with [MATLAB Builder NE](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/netbuilder/), and have your C# app call that.
2. Use [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlab-coder/) to convert your algorithm to C, and integrate that C code directly into your C# app. You would need to make sure that your algorithm falls into the subset of the MATLAB language supported by MATLAB Coder, but if it is primarily a signal processing algorithm it is likely that it will.

I'm not familiar with a specific example that I can point you to of a Windows phone app, but I know that MathWorks have examples of how to apply the second option to generate C code that is integrated into an Objective C application on iPhone.

Ignore the possibility of deploying your code with MATLAB Compiler and integrating the result into your C# app. The executables/libraries created by MATLAB Compiler depend on MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR), which has a much larger footprint than is suitable for a mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

You can not run matlab code in windows phone. For windows phone you must write code in c# ( silverlight, xna) or native c++. 
You wont have any runtime environment for your Matlab code in windows phone.

---

Hack: there are .net bindings for Matlab. You can try them.